# Test API with URL Params in JEST

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, supertest

There is an API endpoint that needs integration tests using Jest.

Here's the endpoint: `http://localhost/universities/ucla/class/2013/studentalis/johndoe`. The request is a put request and it returns 201 on Postman.

However, when I test it:

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("supertest");
const updateStudentRoute= require('../handlers/updateStudent');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/universities/ucla/class/2013/studentalis/johndoe', updateStudentRoute);
describe('Update Student Details in Databse', () => {
    it('Update Student Details in Database', async() => {
        const updateStudentRequestBody = require('./updateStudentRequestBody');
        const response = await request(app).put(`universities/ucla/class/2013/studentalis/johndoe`)
                                           .send(createInstanceRequestBody);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
    });
});
```

The test returns timeout because it got an error in the updateStudent.js file. In it, it is not able to parse the url params:

```
function getQuery(req, studentid, id) {
  return {
    universityName: req.params.universityName.toString(),
    class: req.params.class.toString(),
    studentAlias: req.params.studentAlias.toString()
  };
}
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

```
  226 |   return {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
> 227 |     universityName: req.params.universityName.toString(),                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      |                                               ^
  228 |     class: req.params.class.toString(),
  229 |     studentAlias: req.params.studentAlias.toString()
```

When I debugged, `req` is an object and `req.params` is empty, thus `req.params.universityName.toString()` is `undefined`. So my guess is that the way I set the url params is incorrect. Any leads on what the syntax would be?

Comment: Your route path doesn't have any `:parameter` defined in it, but also why _are_ you re-defining it in the test?

Comment: can you share your API definition?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes you are right. I was following some tutorials on jest and didn't realize it means defining route path until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely `req.params` will be empty because you don't specified any **route parameters**.

> Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL. The captured values are populated in the `req.params` object, with the name of the route parameter specified in the path as their respective keys.

Let see how to define, In your `server.js` or `index.js`
simply specify the route parameters in the path of the route as shown below. For ex: `/path/:name` here name is the route parameter

```
const express = require("express");
const updateStudentRoute= require('../handlers/updateStudent');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
// use put method instead use
app.put('/university/:universityName/class/:class/studentalias/:studentAlias', updateStudentRoute);

app.listen(2000,function(){  
   console.log("Server is running on port 2000");  
});
```

One more thing you are using `app.use` instead use `app.put` because
`app.use()` is intended for binding middleware to your application.

So far you will have an idea about route parameters. Let see how to test them

In your `test` js

```
const supertest = require("supertest");
const request = supertest("http://localhost:2000");

describe('Update Student Details in Databse', () => {
    it('Update Student Details in Database', async() => {
        // const updateStudentRequestBody = require('./updateStudentRequestBody'); put method does not have body
        const response = await request.put(`/university/ucla/class/2013/studentalias/johndoe`); // here you can use the values in place of :name
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
    });
});
```

Passing the `app` instance each time is not necessary, if you're testing the same host you may simply re-assign the request variable with the initialization `url`, a new Test is created per `request.VERB()` call.

Finally don't forget to send the `response` code `201`, because by default express answer all endpoints with 200